# Android layout keep titlebar header and footer always visible with content scrolling under

Tags: android, android-layout

I am trying to make a layout that has dynamic content inside of it and on this screen I also want to show a Titlebar on top and a button as a footer view at the bottom. The titlebar and the footer view should always be visible and everything else should scroll under them.

I tried with a RelativeLayout and gave the title bar a `layout_alignParentTop="true"` and `alignParentBottom="true"` for the button, and this works fine except that when the virtual keyboard is open then the titlebar scrolls off the screen. Is there anyway to keep the titlebar on screen with the content scrolling under it always?

Answer (score 0):

In your AndroidManifest.xml, for the activity in which you desire this behaviour, you can set the windowSoftInput property to "adjustResize"

```
<activity 
    android:name="-Your-Activity-Name-"
    android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize">
</activity>
```